# Создать длинный Base64

Tags: php, base64

Требуется перевести строку в длинный Base64

Строка - sJEBR6YoZTyuwBpiQq70u9vo1At4ZKtoIENxuMU6rPV

Должно получиться - eyJpdiI6InFLV0pJMWxtTkcwNlk0ekVDSGhxU0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWllCNG5OUGVMdG1sbVNxaXZEYklCS3FLZUdhZjh2aGdWbCtROFhKL3FJamluczBFT2lxQWJRSE5KTFBRUCtvaSIsIm1hYyI6IjNkZjJmYmRmNTY3OTRhNzM4OTNiODc4YTQ4NTA3NDM4Njg2ODAxOTNmYTQzNzgzMTI4M2UwZTRjNGRlNzUzNTYiLCJ0YWciOiIifQ==

или

{"iv":"qKWJI1lmNG06Y4zECHhqSA==","value":"ZYB4nNPeLtmlmSqivDbIBKqKeGaf8vhgVl+Q8XJ/qIjins0EOiqAbQHNJLPQP+oi","mac":"3df2fbdf56794a73893b878a4850743868680193fa437831283e0e4c4de75356","tag":""}

Когда я кодирую строку методом через php, я получаю c0pFQlI2WW9aVHl1d0JwaVFxNzB1OXZvMUF0NFpLdG9JRU54dU1VNnJQVg==

`echo base64_encode('sJEBR6YoZTyuwBpiQq70u9vo1At4ZKtoIENxuMU6rPV');`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какое направление рыть

Comment: ну тут явно не base64. тут какое то шифрование, последующее заворачивание в json вместе с ключами шифрования (ну как минимум с вектором iv) и потом уже кодирование этого json в base64

Comment: И еще подозреваю что может использоваться hmac https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, отпишусь потом